# On foreach(var id in ids) Object reference not set to an instance of an object c#

Tags: c#

```
    public void Post(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
        string postIdVal = AddPublicationOnMonster(id);
        string url = string.Format("http://jobview.monster.com/getjob.aspx?JobID={0}",             postIdVal);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url); ;
        }   


    }
```

the error was in the line foreach (var id in ids), how can I solve it ?

Comment: `ids` is null. To solve - don't pass null to this method

Comment: Exception is self-explanatory.

Comment: What do you pass to `Post`, show that code. If you want to ignore if `null` is passed you simply need to check that at the beginning and `return` from the method.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. `ids` is null, because you called `Post` with `null` as the argument (more likely).
2. `ids.GetEnumerator()` returns null, because the actual type of `ids` didn't implement this method correctly (less likely).

Answer (score 0):

Like Sergey said:

```
public void Post(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    if(ids != null)
    {
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            string postIdVal = AddPublicationOnMonster(id);
            string url = string.Format("http://jobview.monster.com/getjob.aspx?JobID={0}",             postIdVal);
             System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url); ;
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before iterate on it, you should check if your collection is instantiated.
Check it for "null" :

```
if (ids != null)
{
    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
    string postIdVal = AddPublicationOnMonster(id);
    string url = string.Format("http://jobview.monster.com/getjob.aspx?JobID={0}",             postIdVal);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url); ;
    }   
}
else
{
    DoSomething();
}
```